# Move/Copy Specific columns data of a table in to another table Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have table filled with data generated from backend.Now I want to copy some Specific column data(tableX) to another new table(tableY) as input text on button click Like the picture below.
[image]

The Problem is I don't know how to specifically copy the specific columns into my new table . That's why I added an **Image**.

**I know  clone/append can copy  whole table and move in to another .But I don't want To copy The whole table data.**

I need to copy only specific columns data into another new table like the image.Straightly I want to fill table Y with some column from table X.

Comment: many error in your code : `var row = $('tableX) .closest('tr').html();`

Comment: i didnt upload the whole code as i said i dont wanna clone or copy the whole table i want like the picture

Comment: Can you post your copy code?

Comment: I said I can't make what i wanted .That's why i added an Image of what I want@Zapurdead

Comment: First of all you have to use the data attributes of HTML to distinguish these columens from each the other then you have to loop through these columens and get the text or inner html and paste it to table two

Comment: How are you selecting your columns by? By their content in the table header? By their zero-based index?

Comment: Umm I Want to do this by column Suppose i want to copy only Column A 's  and B's  data ,and also not sure how it could be done . :(  can you suggest any solution of yours that you think would be best  @Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/2bqf0obs/1/

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
 var col = parseInt($('#cNum').val());
 
 if( $('table#tableX thead tr').children().length >= col){
    if( $('table#tableY thead').children().length === 0 ){
      $('table#tableY thead').append('<tr></tr>');
    }

    $('table#tableY thead tr').append('<th>' +  $($('table#tableX thead tr').children()[col -1]).text() + '</th>');

    $('table#tableX tbody tr').each(function(i){
     if( $('table#tableY tbody').children().length != $('table#tableX tbody').children().length ){
        $('table#tableY tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
     }
      $('table#tableY tbody tr:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').append('<td>' + $($(this).children()[col - 1]).text() + '</tr>');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
table, tr, th, td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableX">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>173</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>333</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

Col Number<input type="text" id="cNum" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<br/>
<table id="tableY">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy... Question was related to specific column. Anyway give me some time, will do it for you.

Comment: Thank you but you don't understand .I don't have any option to input column no in any text box .In on click i have to load the columns so I have to pass the column no inside the code i want that .I hope you understand

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy that also we can help you out... Wait for some time..

Comment: Thanks a lot a lot a lot for helping  , Let me clear again I know which columns  will I Take  just need to copy those into new and all at a time .on a single click@Shailaditya

Comment: Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/2bqf0obs/3/ . .. I have kept both the options. 1st option : click on header it will copy the entire column in new table & 2nd option using input textbox & button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149608/discussion-between-asifuzzaman-redoy-and-shiladitya).

Answer (score 1):

You must loop on the first table `thead` and `tbody` and select the column of the header and body you want to add in the second table with `eq(index).text()`.

And finnaly you create dynamicaly create the second table.

There is a code who works.

```js
$("#table1").find("thead").each(function(){
 $table1Head=$(this).find("th");
 $("#table2 thead").append("<th>"+$table1Head.eq(1).text()+ " </th>");
  $("#table2 thead").append("<th>"+$table1Head.eq(2).text()+ " </th>");
  $("#table2 thead").append("<th>"+$table1Head.eq(4).text()+ " </th>");
  $("#table2 thead").append("<th>"+$table1Head.eq(5).text()+ " </th>");
});

$("#table1 tbody").find("tr").each(function(){
 $table2data=$(this).find("td");
 $("#table2 tbody").append("<tr>"+
   "<td>" + $table2data.eq(1).text() + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + $table2data.eq(2).text() + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + $table2data.eq(4).text() + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + $table2data.eq(5).text() + "</td>" +
  "</tr>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
table 1
</p>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
table 2
</p>
<table id="table2">
<thead>
  
</thead>
<tbody>
  
</tbody>
</table>
```